# Skip validators in Zend Framework 2 Forms

Tags: php, forms, validation, zend-framework2

I am using Zend Framework 2 for building my project. In one of my forms I have a field that needs to be validates with several validators only if a given condition is satisfied (e.g. the value of another form field).

Is there a way to skip completely the validation of a field based on an external condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `setValidationGroup` inside the `InputFilter` class to set what input fields should be validated.

You could for example extend the `InputFilter` class and use the `setValidationGroup` in a customized `setData` method, and set the group depending on the presence of a certain field in `$data`.

For example something like this:

```
<?php

namespace Application\InputFilter;

use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;

class CustomInputFilter extends InputFilter
{
    /**
     * Set data to use when validating and filtering
     *
     * @param  array|Traversable $data
     * @return InputFilterInterface
     */
    public function setData($data)
    {
        $group = array(
            // your custom validation group
        );
        if(isset($data['fieldName'])){
            $this->setValidationGroup($group);
        }

        // Forward to default setData method
        return parent::setData($data);
    }
}
```

Extending the class is just one option to show what is possible. You can of course also `setValidationGroup` somewhere else externally without a customizing the `InputFilter` class.

```
$group = array(
    // your custom validation group
);
$inputFilter->setValidationGroup($group);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. It was a great starting point. Actually I'm using the same methods you proposed but directly on the form and not on the input filter itself, but the substance is the same. Do you know if there is a way to retrieve the current input filter validation group, since there is no getter in the interface?

Comment: @marcosh Apparently this is not available from outside the class. You could add a getter, but when you do `getValues` only the validated fields will be returned. So you know what was validated by checking the keys in the return value.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `$context` argument from `Zend\Validator\ValidatorInterface` to grab the value of the other form element. All you would need is a custom validator and set it on the form element.

For example:

```
use Zend\Validator;
use Zend\Validator\Exception;

class MyCustomValidator implements Validator\ValidatorInterface
{
    public function isValid($value, array $context = [])
    {
        if (! isset($context['name_of_other_field'])) {
            throw new Exception\RuntimeException('name_of_other_field missing.');
        }

        if (1234 === $context['name_of_other_field']) {

            $validator = new Validator\ValidatorChain();

            $validator->attach(new Validator\StringLength(['min' => 8, 'max' => 12]));
            $validator->attach(new Validator\EmailAddress());

            return $validator->isValid($value);
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function getMessages()
    {}
}
```